# rvm install 1.9.3 leading to ImageMagick installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rmagick

I was using Ruby 1.9.2 for my RoR 3.2.11 project

All worked fine until I had to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 because a gem required it. 
By the same occasion I tried to make good use of RVM.

Installed ruby 1.9.3

```
rvm install 1.9.3 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Created `.rvmrc`

```
cd ./my_project/
rvm --create --rvmrc 1.9.3@project
```

Cleaned up my global gemset

```
rvm gemset empty
```

cd into my project and run installed gems

```
bundle
```

Error log

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /usr/local/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.7.3 Q16 is installed in 
         /usr/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.7.1 Q16 is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1
Using 6.7.3 Q16 from .

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@creativebank/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@my_project/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

At first sight, it looks like I have 2 installations of ImageMagick and that I could spare one.

So my first question would be how to uninstall clean ImageMagick version 6.7.1 Q16?

and of course if there is something else I could try to solve this issue.

ADDITIONAL INFO about packages installed

I know that MacPort and Brew don't work well together but I always been worried about removing MacPort in its entirety. Could that be the problem?

```
port list | grep magick

p5-perlmagick                  @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
p5.8-perlmagick                @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
p5.10-perlmagick               @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
p5.12-perlmagick               @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
p5.14-perlmagick               @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
p5.16-perlmagick               @6.8.6-0        perl/p5-perlmagick
php-gmagick                    @1.1.2RC1       php/php-gmagick
php53-gmagick                  @1.1.2RC1       php/php-gmagick
php54-gmagick                  @1.1.2RC1       php/php-gmagick
php55-gmagick                  @1.1.2RC1       php/php-gmagick
php-imagick                    @3.1.0RC2       php/php-imagick
php53-imagick                  @3.1.0RC2       php/php-imagick
php54-imagick                  @3.1.0RC2       php/php-imagick
php55-imagick                  @3.1.0RC2       php/php-imagick
php-magickwand                 @1.0.9-2        php/php-magickwand
php53-magickwand               @1.0.9-2        php/php-magickwand
php54-magickwand               @1.0.9-2        php/php-magickwand
php55-magickwand               @1.0.9-2        php/php-magickwand
php5-gmagick                   @1.1.2RC1       php/php5-gmagick
php5-imagick                   @3.0.1          php/php5-imagick
php5-magickwand                @1.0.9-2        php/php5-magickwand
rb-rmagick                     @2.13.2         ruby/rb-rmagick


brew list

faac        grc     jasper      lame        libtiff     libvpx      pkg-config  wget        xvid
ffmpeg      imagemagick jpeg        libogg      libvorbis   little-cms  theora      x264        yasm
```

UPDATE

Remove MacPorts

```
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

Uninstalled brew ImageMagick and installed it again with brew

Installed XCode latest version

and ran bundle, I do get a different message, C compiler missing ... argh, what should I do next, I am trying installing gcc with brew, but not sure that I am heading the right direction, please help:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2... no
No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@creativebank/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@creativebank/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

GCC 4.2

```
which gcc => /usr/bin/gcc
```

gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

echo $PATH

```
   /bin;/usr/bin;/usr/sbin;/sbin;/usr/local/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@biowatts/bin:/Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin:/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin:/Users/joel/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin;usr/local/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/joel
```

NEW ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Installing json (1.8.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@biowatts/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@biowatts/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

It obviously looking for /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 which I deleted recklessly while following these instructions to [move from Macportd to homebrew](http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/)  :(

NOW INSTALLING MISSING PACKAGES with homebrew

brew install apple-gcc42 
brew install libxml2

Comment: WOOOOOOW where the f**k you got that path? And why do you have all rvm rubies in path, is it black magick or you're doing something dumb?

Comment: Also, you should start reading error messages - it clearly says what the problem is now. (tip: something you should remove from path)

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

1. Remove MacPorts (you may list all things you installed with them and reinstall those with brew)
2. Remove imagemagick from homebrew
3. Install imagemagick again with brew

You're getting this error `You have to install development tools first.` which (I guess) means you need to install XCode command line tools.

Then `bundle install` should work!

Comment: Oh I did that and installed Latest XCode ... removing MacPorts was pretty scary, I have now a new error. Check update on my question post

Comment: Now the error is "No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details." so there's still something wrong! Could you add result of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Michael, to remove MacPorts I blindly used these instructions http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/ and delete /opt/local without backup cause I thought I'd be able to get it from my timemachine. I still should, but I haven't figured out how. I do have GCC 4.2 installed and I included it in my PATH. I'll update my question with this additional info. I am still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reinstall your ruby after removing the package manager you used to install it, the easiest way is to:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p429
```

Answer (score 0):

In combination to the 2 first answers

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
```

and used http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/

Then in my .bash_profile I set

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig 
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6
```

and finally

```
bundle
```